# Writing table data in to multiple CSV files in java

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle

I have a table called employee having 10 000 records.

I have to write these data into multiple CSV files having 2 000 records each by using multithreading Java.

Sample code is below:

```
    public class PrintbyThreads {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Runnable worker = new PrintFiles("" + i);
            executor.execute(worker);
          }
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        }
        System.out.println("Finished all threads");
    }
}
```

and

```
public class PrintFiles extends Thread implements Runnable {
    private String command;

    PrintFiles() {
        super("my extending thread");
        System.out.println("my thread created" + this);
        start();
    }

    public PrintFiles(String command) {
        this.command = command;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                + " Start. Command = " + command);
        dataBaseExecution();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " End. Command ="
                + command);
    }

    public synchronized void dataBaseExecution() {
        String tableName = "Employee";
        String filename = "D:/db2csv/";
        int recordsAtTime = 2000;
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "URL", "Uname", "Password");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt.setFetchSize(recordsAtTime);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select empid,empname,managerid from Employee");
            int columnCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename + "" + tableName + ".csv");
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                fw.append(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
                fw.append(",");

            }
            fw.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            while (rs.next()) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                    if (rs.getObject(i) != null) {
                        String data = rs.getObject(i).toString();
                        fw.append(data);
                        fw.append(",");
                    } else {
                        String data = "null";
                        fw.append(data);
                        fw.append(",");
                    }

                }
                // new line entered after each row
                fw.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }

            fw.flush();
            fw.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.command;
    }
}
```

My code is giving single CSV file having all 10000 records.but I need 5 CSV files having 2000 records in each.

Thread1 has to process first 2000 records into employee1.csv

Thread 2 has to process another 2000 records into employee2.csv

,,,,,Etc.

By using my code of threading, how can I achieve this requirement?

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question ... Your question is way too broad; it reads like "please do my work for me"

Comment: Sorry. I have a program too. But due to some security reason, I am not  writing code here. i don't need complete code. Just little logic to create one more CSV file if 2000 records reached..

Comment: Nobody says that you need to put up your *production* code. Put up a [mcve]! Otherwise you will receive **nothing** but downvotes and close requests.

Comment: you should include a question in your question.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you may need a partitioner which will give you a from index and to index  the thread needs to process.

public class MyPartitioner {

```
public Map partition(int gridSize,int range) {

    Map partitionMap = new HashMap();
    int startingIndex = 0;
    int endingIndex = range;

    for(int i=0; i< gridSize; i++){
      Map threadMap = new HashMap();

        threadMap.putInt("startingIndex",startingIndex);
        threadMap.putInt("endingIndex", endingIndex);

        startingIndex = endingIndex+1;
        endingIndex += range; 

        partitionMap.put("Thread:-"+i, threadMap);
    }

    return partitionMap;
}
```

}

Executor framework use this from index and to index for worker thread to process the allocated row not all row.
in your select query use in filter condition

```
where id >= :fromId and id <= :toId
```